# Trouble parsing string to date c# (from sqlite database)

Tags: c#, sqlite, datetime

I modeled the solution on answers to many other posts but it still does not work.

```
public void dtParsing()
{
    string date = "2016-04-19 15:14:19.597";
    Console.WriteLine("date as C# string : {0} : ", date);
    string pattern = "yyyy-M-d H:m:s.f";
    DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(date, pattern, null);
    Console.WriteLine("\ndate as C# datetime : {0} : ", myDate.ToString());
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

One problem is that values are not a set number of digits: milliseconds can be anywhere from 0 to 3 digits. Is there a solution without parsing more manual parsing?

Comment: The exception is  "System.FormatException" and the hint "When converting a string to DateTIme, parse the string to take the date before putting each variable into the DateTime object.

Comment: string pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff";

Answer (score 0):

This should stop the error (no need for the pattern, that must match exactly)

```
DateTime myDate = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code

```
        string date = "2016-04-19 15:14:19.597";
        Console.WriteLine("date as C# string : {0} : ", date);
        DateTime myDate = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
        Console.WriteLine("\ndate as C# datetime : {0} : ", myDate.ToString());
        Console.ReadKey();
```

will output

[image: screenshot of code output]

or you can keep the string pattern and get the same results

```
        string date = "2016-04-19 15:14:19.597";
        Console.WriteLine("date as C# string : {0} : ", date);
        string pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff";
        DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(date, pattern, null);
        Console.WriteLine("\ndate as C# datetime : {0} : ", myDate.ToString());
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Yes milliseconds can be anywhere from 0 to 3 digits, but in reality milliseconds will always be 3 digits. Like so: 5 milliseconds is actually .005 .

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `DateTime.ParseExact` here since your milliseconds can be one of `f`, `ff` or `fff` formats which breaks the meaning of *exact* concept.

`DateTime.Parse` can successfully parse your string with a *proper* culture like [`InvariantCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture).

```
DateTime dt;
dt = DateTime.Parse("2016-04-19 15:14:19", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
// Successfull
dt = DateTime.Parse("2016-04-19 15:14:19.5", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
// Successfull
dt = DateTime.Parse("2016-04-19 15:14:19.59", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
// Successfull
dt = DateTime.Parse("2016-04-19 15:14:19.597", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
// Successfull
```

Be aware, using `null` as an `IFormatProvider` *might* be confusing since that means it should use `CurrentCulture` settings, your current culture might not use successfully parse this string because of `:` as a [`TimeSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.timeseparator) and/or not using `GregorianCalendar` as a [`Calendar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.calendar) property.

For example, `ar-SA` culture can't parse your string it uses [`UmAlQuraCalendar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.umalquracalendar) as a `Calendar`.